# This function is giving SIGSEGV error. Can anybody correct and tell em the problem? C++

Tags: c++, vector

```
vector<int> cutTheSticks(vector<int> arr) {

    vector<int> a;
    int i,min;
    int n = arr.size();
    a.push_back(n);

    while(arr.size() > 0){

        min = *min_element(arr.begin(),arr.end());

        for(auto j=arr.begin();j!=arr.end();j++){
            if(*j == min){
                arr.erase(j);
                //Problem lies here
            }
            else{
                *j = *j-min;
            }
        }
        a.push_back(arr.size());
    }
    return a;
}
```

This function is giving SIGSEGV error. Can anybody correct and tell me the problem?

Comment: Suppose `arr` is an empty vector; then `min_element()` will return `arr.end()`, which doesn't have a value to dereference; this is why it's always bad to immediately dereference the iterators returned by STL algorithms. This probably isn't your exact failure case, but something to consider. That said, run it through a debugger! There are a few places where this could generate SIGSEGV, and I'm sure we don't want to bash them all in this question!

Comment: @jhill515 How `arr` can be empty after the condition `while(arr.size() > 0)`?

Comment: @S.M., good point -- I missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the chosen loop.

```
for (auto j = arr.begin(); j != arr.end(); j++) {
  if(*j == min){
    arr.erase(j);
  } else {
    *j = *j - min;
  }
}
```

Suppose `j` points the last element in the array, i.e. it is `arr.end() - 1`. After `arr.erase(j);` the iterator `j` is invalid and `j++` on next iteration is undefined behavior, probably it advances `j` behind `arr.end()`.
Correct the loop like below

```
auto j = arr.begin();
while (j != arr.end()) {
  if(*j == min){
    j = arr.erase(j);
  } else {
    *j = *j - min;
    ++j;
  }
}
```

Comment: Bro can u tell a little more about how   j = arr.erase(j);  is working??

Comment: [std::vector<T,Allocator>::erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)